# スプレッドシートで別の列同士の文字を結合して１つに列にしたい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

CSVをはりつけてテキストを列に分割ってできますよね
あれと逆のことをしたいんですが方法はありませんか？
特に分割文字と入れなくて良くてただ連結するだけでいいです

一応CONCAT関数で列同士を連結した別の列を作ることはできるんですが
その結果列を演算結果ではなく文字列として固定して
ソースとなった列を削除できればいいんですがそういうことって可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CONCATENATE 関数](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=ja)や [JOIN 関数](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=ja)を使えば文字列の結合を行えます。

演算結果を式ではなく値として保存するには、特殊貼り付けの「値のみ貼り付け」を使う方法があります。つまり、セルの計算式を貼り付けるのではなくて、コピーしたセルの計算結果である値自体を貼り付けることができます。右クリックメニューから「特殊貼り付け」を選ぶことで行えます。

Comment: できました！　ありがとうございます